# Using as.POSIXct in R giving na for identical character structures

Tags: r, timestamp

I have two timestamps in character form that I want to convert to a POSIX format in R.
The `timestamps` are:

```
1: "2013-03-30 17:45:00"

2: "2013-03-31 02:05:00"
```

The first one converts fine, the second one gives me `NA`. The `timestamps` are downloaded as `characters` from an `SQL server`. Anyone have any ideas what is going wrong?

I don't have the reputation to attach a screenshot, so a screenshot of my R console showing the result is provided here: http://emillarsen.com/r%20console.jpg

Comment: it works fine for me. Could it be that your data.frame has the strings as factors ? Try adding `as.character` to the call if that helps then that is it. `a="2013-03-31 02:05:00"; as.POSIXct(as.character(a), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: What is your locale? Daylight savings started in the UK on that day.

Comment: Just set the timezone to one without DST, e.g., to `tz="GMT"`. My generic advice is to always set the `tz` parameter explicitly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like a DST issue. I assume from your name you are from [Sweden](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=239&year=2013) or thereabouts. There was no time in Sweden between 2am and 3am on the 31st March 2013, as the clocks went forward then.

```
as.POSIXct("2013-03-31 02:05:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="Europe/Stockholm")
[1] NA
```

This is true for anyone on Central European Time (CET).

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me. As people in the forum commented -might be `TimeZone` issues. However i have added ways of doing it.
one way of converting character value to POSIXct:

```
  dates <- c("1992-02-27", "1992-02-27", "1992-01-14", "1992-02-28", "1992-01-02")
  times <- c("23:03:20", "22:29:56", "01:03:30", "18:21:03", "16:56:26")
  X <- paste(dates, times)

  str(x)
  chr [1:5] "1992-02-27 23:03:20" "1992-02-27 22:29:56" ...

  dt <- strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  dt
[1] "1992-02-27 23:03:20" "1992-02-27 22:29:56" "1992-01-14 01:03:30"
[4] "1992-02-28 18:21:03" "1992-01-02 16:56:26"  

  str(dt) 
  POSIXlt[1:5], format: "1992-02-27 23:03:20" "1992-02-27 22:29:56" ...
```

Another Way: as you approached

```
> now <- Sys.time()
> now
[1] "2014-01-16 16:58:23 IST"
> as.POSIXlt(as.character(now),tz="GMT")
[1] "2014-01-16 17:05:24 GMT"
> str(as.POSIXlt(now))
 POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2014-01-16 16:58:23"
> unclass(as.POSIXlt(now))
$sec
[1] 23.1636

$min
[1] 58

$hour
[1] 16

$mday
[1] 16

$mon
[1] 0

$year
[1] 114

$wday
[1] 4

$yday
[1] 15

$isdst
[1] 0

attr(,"tzone")
[1] ""    "IST" "IST"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same problem.

One way that I found to solve that was changing to `GMT` my `Timezone` in `tz="GMT"`:

```
as.POSIXct(x = c("2013-03-31 02:05:00"),
           format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
           tz="GMT"
)

# [1] "2013-03-31 02:05:00 GMT"
```