# R POSIXct sometimes return NA in df with similar datetime formats

Tags: r, datetime, posix, na, posixct

I have a long dataframe (about 1e6 rows) that looks like this:

```
DF <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              date = c("2012-03-25 00:00:00",
                       "2012-03-25 01:00:00","2012-03-25 02:00:00",
                       "2012-03-25 03:00:00","2012-03-25 04:00:00","2012-03-25 05:00:00"),
                ID = c("KGM00167","KGM00167",
                       "KGM00167","KGM00167","KGM00167","KGM00167"),
             value = c(-6526.388611,-7.470833333,
                       -8280.555833,-8597.221389,-7419.444722,-0.0083)
)

as.POSIXct(DF$date[3], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I'm trying to read this table into R and convert the first column into POSXct format.
For some reason some dates are converted to NA values (e.g. in this table the third row returns as NA)
I cannot figure why this happen as the format seems similar.

Does someone understand why this happens?

The code I have used is as follows:

`df <- read.table(csv, sep = ",", header = T,  fill = T) %>% select(date, ID, value) %>%  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))`

Comment: Given the dates, I suspect it is due to Daylight Saving Time starting, and that hour being skipped. You might be able to get round it by explicitly specifying a timezone.

Comment: I guess it is the same issue as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21160542/9841389). E.g.: `as.POSIXct(DF$date[3], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")` does not result in `NA`.

Comment: According to https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2012.html, many countries used March 25, 2012 for their early-year DST.

Comment: Jan., a lesson learned from my "fun with timestamps": if you know the time zone of the origin of the data, always always always specify it with `as.POSIXct`. Even if you immediately change it to a preferred TZ, at least you won't run into problems like this. There are too many nuances and corner-cases that make any assumptions in code very fun bugs to troubleshoot, this being one of them.

Comment: Thanks, it indeed was caused by the Daylight savings time, including the timezone (tz='UTC') did resolve the problem.